# is gradle 6.0 implemention include project class in class path

Tags: java, gradle

I am including a project using in Gradle 6.0:

```
implementation project(":soa-wallet:soa-wallet-api")
```

it compiles success but when I run the app, it throws error:

```
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sportswin.soa.wallet.AppStarter.main(AppStarter.java:32) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/sportswin/soa/wallet/controller/IFeignClientWalletConsumeRecordController.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
```

`IFeignClientWalletConsumeRecordController` is in the reference project,why dit not found class in runtime? What should I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: If it gets instantiated through reflection, it will not give compilation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the `org.springframework.boot` plugin package my `soa-wallet-api` to an application automatic,not a library,so using this lib could not found class,solve the problem,you can use this code to enable lib package:

```
 jar{
        // enable package thin Jar
        enabled = true
    }
```

this should fix this problem.